# rowspan not working as expected on second row

Tags: html, html-table

Why doesn't the top "1 2 3" line up with the bottom "1 2 3"?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td rowspan="3">⟶</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td rowspan="3">⟶</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All rows need to have the same number of cells, or if rowspans are used, those have to sum up with the number of regular (not-rowspanning) cells.
Your first row has 3 cells, the second one 6. That can't work. If you insert those row-spanning cells in the first row (like in my adaption of your snippet below), it will work.

```css
td { border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">⟶</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td rowspan="3">⟶</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: :facepalm: It's been a while since I used tables.  Thanks!